# javascript with select box that changes event

Tags: javascript, html, select, button, input

i have a table in javascript (you can find the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/webYa73/xuw23/)

If i choose  "case6" in the select box, a button appears near the input field (3cols),  the edit button should change and instead we should see a save button and a cancel button

how can i implement that in javascript?
please help
thanks

Comment: i'm really new in Javascript, and i have no idea how to do it

Comment: Please stop reposting the same question

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind an onChange event to the select box to trigger call a function when the box changes
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Include the save and cancel elements in the document but mark them as hidden
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp

When the onchange event fires remove the hidden property from the save and cancel and add a hidden property to the edit button.

You will probably find this easier if you use the JQuery library
http://jquery.com/

Also from looking at your code you might want to learn about iteration and create your option boxes with a for loop rather than writing:

```
    var opt1 = document.createElement("option");
    var opt2 = document.createElement("option");
    var opt3 = document.createElement("option");
    var opt4 = document.createElement("option");
    var opt5 = document.createElement("option");
    var opt6 = document.createElement("option");
    var opt7 = document.createElement("option");
```

Hope that helps